# PHP echo session value to a new session?

Tags: php

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

```
$_SESSION["new"] = "This are the values of $_SESSION['A'] & $_SESSION['B']";
```

I want to echo the "new" session value on a different page for my user to check.

I tried various things such as the code below but it doesn't work.

```
$_SESSION["new"] = <?php echo $_SESSION['A']?>;
```

Comment: to assign a value, you don't need to `echo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can assign multiple session variables by using the concatenation operator.

```
$_SESSION["new"] = "This are the values of  ".$_SESSION['A']."&".$_SESSION['B'];
```

On the page, you want to display, simply print the session variable.

```
echo $_SESSION["new"];
```

Please make sure,on both pages, you are using **session_start()** function

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION["new"] = 'foo bar';
```

You can simply assign any value to your session variables. you can read more [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php)

if you are sure of the type of value in `$_SESSION["A"]` and `$_SESSION["B"]`, and assuming in your case they are both string, you can do the following:

```
$_SESSION["new"] = sprintf('This are the values of %s & %s', $_SESSION['A'], $_SESSION['B']);
```